# suggested sources for recent apache on Ubuntu 8.10

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2

I need to run the latest Apache (2.2.13) on Ubuntu 8.10, and am *extremely* averse to compiling from source or building my own .deb because of cloud hosting issues. Even Canonical's intrepid-backports repository only has Apache 2.2.9.

Can anybody suggest a good sources.list repository for Apache 2.2.13 on Ubuntu 8.10?

Comment: why that specific edition of Apache 2.2?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the Jaunty or Karmic repositories for a .deb?
What is the cloud hosting issue with rolling your own .deb, vs. grabbing one via apt?

Comment: I'd have to then either put the .deb in some perpetually-available filestore or set up my own repository, both of which are a pain for simply upgrading Apache. Using Karmic might be an option (though it only brings me up to .12, not to .13) -- but I'm somewhat afraid of the dependency thicket that comes with that. Many thanks for that suggestion though.